# Showing inversion preserves lines and circles

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \ z\mapsto 1/z$. Then I can see that if $||z-a||=r $ where $a \in \mathbb{C}, r>0 $ then setting $w=f(z)$ we get $r=||z-a||=\frac{||aw-1||}{||w||}.$
How is this a circle or line?
Also if $z=a+bt $ a line, then $w=1/(a+bt)$ but how is this a line or circle?

Comment: This is proved on Conway's Functions of one  Complex Variable.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch:

The general equation of a circle in polar coordinates is $r^2+(A\cos t+B\sin t)r+C=0$ and $f$ transforms $r \to 1/r, t \to -t$ so it is immediate that the equation above gets transformed into a similar one, namely $r^2+(A\cos t-B\sin t)r/C+1/C=0$ unless $C=0$ (which means the original circle goes through the origin so the transformed one goes through infinity) when we get a line $1+(A\cos t-B\sin t)r=0$.

Similarly for a line $(A\cos t+B\sin t)r+C=0$ - if it goes through the origin so $C=0$ and the equation reduces to $A\cos t+B \sin t=0$, then the transform remains a line, namely $A\cos t-B \sin t=0$; otherwise when $C \ne 0$ the transform becomes a circle going through the origin with equation $r^2+(A\cos t-B\sin t)r/C=0$